# Adding Pinch/Zoom effect to a UIImageView inside a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, nsrunloop

I have a very basic screen sharing iPhone app, I have successfully added the pinch/zoom effect to my app using a `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView`.

The `UIImageView` receives the screen content from the PC on a regular interval. Everything works fine but as soon as I scroll/pinch/zoom it works at first but then it stops, and the delegate method that's updating the image view content stops firing up even though the server still sends the screen content. The whole app seems to be frozen but there are no error messages/exceptions/whatever. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Might this be a threading issue? Do you do update all your views on the main thread?

Comment: Updating the UIImage view works fine, the problem occur as soon as I start pinching/zooming

Comment: How do you update the image of the image view? And by pinch and zoom, you mean you've implemented your own or did you use `viewForZooming` method.

Comment: I have a singleton class that does the networking stuff for me. When an image is received, a delegate (that I have created) fires up, and my viewController who implements that delegate handle the updating process.
for the pinch/zoom, I have used the `viewForZooming` method.

Comment: R u using any runloop(CADisplaylink)in your app...

Comment: @Chandan I'm not sure what you mean by that, care to explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`, `UIAPPlication` adds a run loop mode `UITrackingRunLoopMode` for tracking scrollview events like scrolling. Since the `UIApplication` switches from `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` to `UITrackingRunLoopMode` any events on `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` will not be called until `UIAPPlication` switch back to  `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`.

It might be the problem, the fix is change `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` to **`NSRunLoopCommonModes`** .

If you are not sure whether you are using runloop or not as you mentioned in comment. Just search `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` in your project.

Comment: Thank you so much, changing from NSDefaultRunLoopMode to NSRunLoopCommonModes solved my problem.

Comment: I don't know how to find the NSDefaultRunLoopMode