# is it possible to have zoom effects without using scroll view? (iOS)

Tags: ios, zooming, scrollview

Hi guys as a beginner i want to know that is it possible to have zoom and pan effects without using scroll view for iOS? if yes then how can I do that?

[refered this kind of questions but got no clue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370629/uiscrollview-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-doesnt-work-properly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YES You can Do that without scrollview.plz see below link

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uigesturerecognizer/